# how to load Html page on Web View on Button click in windows Phone Blank application?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net

i want to load the Html string on web view. i tried this. but its giving an exception. can anyone please suggest something.

async void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WebView1.Loaded += WebView1_Loaded;
            string htmlFragment =@"
    
        
            Function Hello()
            {
                document.getElementById('myDiv').innerText += 'Hello ';
            }
        
    
    
        Welcome to C-Sharpcorner
     
";

```
        WebView1.NavigateToString(htmlFragment);
        WebView1.InvokeScriptAsync("Hello",null);


    }
```

it gives an exception 'System.NotImplementedException' .

Comment: i got answer of it.. i just called the InvokeScriptAsync() method in MyWebView_NavigationCompleted()...